# When outputting commands from cmd.exe (CreatProcess) I get "More?" Why and how to get rid of it?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd, createprocess

I have a problem with the second output from cmd.exe.
I use: CreatePipe () to link processes; CreateProcess () to create a process that runs 'cmd.exe'.

The problem is that I cannot get the correct output from cmd.exe

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;


#define deffBuffSize 4096


int funCo() {

    HANDLE writeToCL, readFromCL, writeToProcess, readFromProcess;
    char lpCmdLine[] = "cmd.exe", lpCL[512];
    memset(lpCL, '\0', 512);
    if (GetEnvironmentVariableA("COMSPEC", lpCL, 512) == 0) {
        cout << "GetEnvironmentVariableA error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << lpCL << endl;
    STARTUPINFOA siA;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piApp;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttr;
    ZeroMemory(&secAttr, sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES));
    ZeroMemory(&siA, sizeof(STARTUPINFOA));
    secAttr.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    secAttr.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    secAttr.bInheritHandle = TRUE;

    if (CreatePipe(&readFromCL, &writeToProcess, &secAttr, 0) == 0) {
        cout << "Create pipe error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(readFromCL, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT)) {
        cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    if (CreatePipe(&readFromProcess, &writeToCL, &secAttr, 0) == 0) {
        cout << "Create pipe error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    if (!SetHandleInformation(writeToCL, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT, HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT)) {
        cout << "SetHandleInformation error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
    }

    siA.cb = sizeof(STARTUPINFOA);
    siA.hStdInput = readFromProcess;
    siA.hStdOutput = writeToProcess;
    siA.hStdError = writeToProcess;
    siA.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;


    if (CreateProcessA(lpCL, NULL, NULL, NULL, TRUE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, &siA, &piApp) == 0) {
        cout << "CreateProcessA error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    
    CloseHandle(readFromProcess);
    CloseHandle(writeToProcess);

    Sleep(2000);
    DWORD dRead = 0, dWrite = 0;
    char chBuff[deffBuffSize];
    memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
    if (ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL) == FALSE) {
        cout << "ReadFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << chBuff;

    for (;;) {
        memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
        fgets(chBuff, deffBuffSize, stdin);
        if (WriteFile(writeToCL, chBuff, sizeof(chBuff), &dWrite, NULL) == FALSE) {
            cout << "WriteFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        Sleep(2000);
        memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
        if (ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL) == FALSE) {
            cout << "ReadFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << chBuff;

    }

    CloseHandle(writeToCL);
    CloseHandle(readFromCL);
    CloseHandle(piApp.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piApp.hThread);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int result = 0;
    result = funCo();
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return result;
}
```

[image: Console output of parent process]

- The yellow marker is the command entered by the user.
- Red marker - output of the command result.

**If the output is "More?" press ENTER, then we will receive an error that ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE (109) - The pipe has been ended.**

[image: Error screenshot]

How do I understand "More?" writes if you want to display the next sheet of information.

But how to get around this "More?"

Help please, I will be very grateful to you. =)

**The part below relates to comments:**

**Autoscroll not disabled**

[image: cmd -> Properties]

**I tried using a static command when writing to cmd.exe**

But after this action I find myself in a "deadlock"

```
Sleep(2000);
    DWORD dRead = 0, dWrite = 0;
    char chBuff[deffBuffSize];
    memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
    if (ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL) == FALSE) {
        cout << "ReadFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    cout << chBuff;
    char outMes[] = "ipconfig\0";

    for (;;) {
        /*memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
        fgets(chBuff, deffBuffSize, stdin);*/
        
        if (WriteFile(writeToCL, outMes, sizeof(outMes), &dWrite, NULL) == FALSE) {
            cout << "WriteFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << "WriteFile :: " << dWrite << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
        if (ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL) == FALSE) {
            cout << "ReadFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
            return 1;
        }
        cout << chBuff;

    }
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221015/discussion-on-question-by-berserkhacker-when-outputting-commands-from-cmd-exe-c).

Comment: If this issue has been solved, can you kindly share your solution as an answer? It will be helpful for others are searching on similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole mistake was that I:

1. Used "\0"
2. WriteFile (writeToCL, outMes, sizeof (outMes) - 1, & dWrite, NULL)
   wrote two characters "\0"

This program endlessly enters and receives information about ipconfig

The command line takes the command like this: [i][p][c][o][n][f][i][g][\n][\0]

```
char outMes[] = "ipconfig\n";

for (;;) {
if (WriteFile(writeToCL, outMes, sizeof(outMes) - 1, &dWrite, NULL) == FALSE) {
cout << GetLastError() << " :: error WriteFile" << endl;
return 1;
}
Sleep(2000);
memset(chBuff, '\0', deffBuffSize);
if (ReadFile(readFromCL, chBuff, deffBuffSize, &dRead, NULL) == FALSE) {
cout << "ReadFile error :: " << GetLastError() << endl;
return 1;
}
cout << chBuff;

}
```

P.S: Use strlen to determine the length of a string.
instead sizeof()